# Material-table Picker month and date getting swapped

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datepicker, mui-x-date-picker

Hi have a table where when i click on edit the picker should fetch saved date and allow me to save the date , but as of now if the saved date is  in dd-MM-yyyy as soon as i click on edit it automatically changes to MM-dd-yyyy, where as when i console log the value of picker it is still coming in dd-MM-yyyy format not sure what is going wrong

`

`````
 import { format } from 'date-fns'; 
    import {
  Typography,
  TableRow,
  TableCell,
  Button,
  TextField,
  Switch
    } from '@material-ui/core';
   import { DatePicker } from '@material-ui/pickers';

-   const Tablelist= ({
   }) => {
  const [editedRows, setEditedRows] = useState({});

  const editClick = extensionRequestId => {
    const index = exchangeRequestData.findIndex(
      data => data.extensionRequestId === extensionRequestId
    );

    const originalData = exchangeRequestData[index];
    const editedData = editedRows[extensionRequestId];
    if (!editedData) {
      setEditedRows(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        [extensionRequestId]: {
          extensionExpiryDate: originalData.extensionExpiryDate
        }
      }));
    }
  };

  const cancelClick = () => {
    setEditedRows({});
  };

     const saveClick = async extensionRequestId => {
    const editedData = editedRows[extensionRequestId];
    const index = exchangeRequestData.findIndex(
      data => data.extensionRequestId === extensionRequestId
    );

    const originalData = exchangeRequestData[index];
    if (
      editedData.extensionExpiryDate !== originalData.extensionExpiryDate
    ) {
      const formattedDate =
        editedData.extensionExpiryDate || originalData.extensionExpiryDate;
      const data = {
        date: formattedDate,
        
      };
      api(data)
      
    }

    setEditedRows(prevState => {
      const newState = { ...prevState };
      delete newState[extensionRequestId];
      return newState;
    });
  };

    const abc = orgProfileId => {
    console.log(orgProfileId);
    return orgProfileId;
  };
 
    return (
    <>
      {exchangeRequestData &&
        exchangeRequestData.length > 0 &&
        exchangeRequestData.map(k => (
          <TableRow
            key={k.extensionRequestId}
            className={editedRows[k.extensionRequestId] ? 'isedit' : ''}
           '>
            
            <TableCell >
              {editedRows[k.extensionRequestId] ? (
                <DatePicker
                  required
                  autoOk
                  inputVariant='outlined'
                  format='dd-MM-yyyy'
                  label='Expiry Date'
                  value={abc(
                    editedRows[k.extensionRequestId].extensionExpiryDate
                  )}
                  onChange={date => {
                    setEditedRows(prevState => ({
                      ...prevState,
                      [k.extensionRequestId]: {
                        ...prevState[k.extensionRequestId],
                        extensionExpiryDate: date
                      }
                    }));
                  }}
                />
              ) : (
                <Typography data-test='product-name'>
                  {k.extensionExpiryDate}
                </Typography>
              )}
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell
              align='center'
              data-test='extension-request-Table-Cell-buttun-container'>
              {editedRows[k.extensionRequestId] ? (
                <>
                  <Button
                    variant='contained'
                    color='primary'
                    size='small'
                    data-test='save-button'
                    onClick={() => saveClick(k.extensionRequestId)}>
                    Save
                  </Button>
                  <Button
                    color='secondary'
                    variant='outlined'
                    type='reset'
                    size='small'
                    className='user-reset-btn'
                    data-test='cancel-button'
                    onClick={cancelClick}>
                    Cancel
                  </Button>
                </>
              ) : (
                <Button
                  data-test='edit-button'
                  onClick={() => editClick(k.extensionRequestId)}>
                  <EditIcon />
                </Button>
              )}
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        ))}
    </>
   );
    };

    export default Tablelist;````
Hi have a table where when i click on edit the picker should fetch saved date and allow me to save the date , but as of now if the saved date is  in dd-MM-yyyy as soon as i click on edit it automatically changes to MM-dd-yyyy, where as when i console log the value of picker it is still coming in dd-MM-yyyy format not sure what is going wrong
 i want to display and also see and edit in dd-MM-yyyy format
`````